# The number “1” on my keyboard only works when I am playing games. Not during normal PC use

Tags: windows-10

It’s not the number <kbd>1</kbd> on the number pad but the normal keyboard number <kbd>1</kbd> since I don’t have a number pad.

It works while I’m playing but not during normal PC usage, like password, writing, etc…

It works perfectly fine on my sister’s notebook but on my PC, it doesn’t.

I tried other keyboards, but the same thing happened, so it’s not a hardware issue. It's just the one that is not working.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you accessibility features or sticky keys turned on? That might do what you see. Turn all keyboard accessibility features off, restart and test.

Comment: I would recommend going to this online keyboard testing site and see if “1” is recognized.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it recognizes it but when i try to type it it doesn't work. Also the exclamation works too

Comment: @John there is nothing eneble in acessibility features and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Sec_Chlorine So when you use a [site like this one](https://keyboardchecker.com) it recognizes the key press, but nothing shows up? That is damned strange.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it is indeed

Answer (score 2):

Likely it is some process intercepting the key message.

- Start Windows in Safe Mode to disable most processes.
- If <kbd>1</kbd> works, that confirms it so try the following:

  - Open Task Manager, open Details tab, sort by name, and make and save screen shots of all.
  - Restart in normal mode.
  - Compare process now running in Task Manager with those from Safe Mode and look for some background process that's interfering.

Comment: how do i know wich one is causing it

Comment: The process name might be a hint, e.g. AutoHotkey, which intercepts keystrokes. Also, by elimination: kill a process, see if "1" works.